# How can I build eRadio from source?

Tags: software-installation

Since the dreamdev repository went away several months ago the application must be built from source. How can users do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd /usr/local/src; git clone https://github.com/DreamDevel/eRadio.git
cd eRadio/tools; . dev-shell; ./install-deps
mkdir ../build; build; cd ../build; sudo make install`